# How to remove multiplicities from for a list in way meeting special criteria

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of pairs, `tabul`, which has the property that the second element of each pair is also an element in my list `data`. I want to reduce `tabul` so that has the same length as `data` and meets the following criteria:

1. each element of `data` is contained in `tabul` exactly once
2. in the retained pairs, `Abs[x - y]` is minimized for each y ∈ `data`

The lists `tabul` and `data` are given here.

```
 data = {-1011.7`, -386.7`, 93.3`, 345.3`, 345.3`, 1688.3`};
 tabul = 
  {{-376.0786041017524`, -386.7`}, -410.4424666210672`,-386.7`}, 
   {-1028.4025915824375`, -1011.7`}, {-399.10959105211384`,-386.7`},
   {-441.0293595101775`, -386.7`}, {325.51004782358063`,345.3`},
   {291.1461853042659`,345.3`},{-368.73370811516816`, -386.7`},
   {1697.3159559387486`, 1688.3`}, {43.36333751931454`, 93.3`}};
```

The result I want is here.

```
result = 
  {{-376.0786041017524`, -386.7`}, {-1028.4025915824375`,-1011.7`}, 
   {325.51004782358063`, 345.3`}, {291.1461853042659`, 345.3`}, 
   {1697.3159559387486`, 1688.3`}, {43.36333751931454`,93.3`}}.
```

My code follows, but it does not produce the desired result.

```
pos = Flatten[Map[Position[data, #] &, tabul[[All, 2]]]]
mod = Commonest[pos, 1]
cp = data[[mod]][[1]]
sel = Cases[tabul, {_, cp}]
DeleteDuplicates[
  tabul, 
  sel[[All, #1]] - sel[[All, #2]] & > Min[Abs[sel[[All, 1]] - sel[[All, 2]]]]]
```

Comment: This seems to to the trick: `Module[{mark}, 
   Flatten[Take[#, 
       Count[#, {mark, _}]] & /@ (SortBy[#, Abs[Differences@#] &] & /@
        GatherBy[Join[#2, {mark, #} & /@ #1], Last]), 
    1]] &[data, tabul]`

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {-1011.7, -386.7, 93.3, 345.3, 345.3, 1688.3}; 
tabul = {{-376.079, -386.7}, {-410.442, -386.7}, 
         {-1028.4, -1011.7}, {-399.11, -386.7}, 
         {-441.029, -386.7}, {325.51, 345.3}, 
         {291.146, 345.3}, {-368.734, -386.7}, 
         {1697.32, 1688.3}, {43.3633, 93.3}};
```

The strategy is to first group the pairs in `tabul` by their 2-nd element and sort the each of the groups by `Abs[x - y]`.

```
groups = 
  SortBy[
    SortBy[Abs[#[[1]] - #[[2]]] &] /@ GatherBy[tabul, Last], 
    Last /* First]
```

> ```
> {{{-1028.4, -1011.7}}, 
>  {{-376.079, -386.7}, {-399.11, -386.7}, {-368.734, -386.7}, {-410.442, -386.7}, {-441.029, -386.7}}, 
>  {{43.3633, 93.3}}, 
>  {{325.51, 345.3}, {291.146, 345.3}}, 
>  {{1697.32, 1688.3}}}
> ```

The second stop is to get a list of the multiplicities.

```
m = Last /@ Sort @ Tally[data]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 2, 1}
> ```

The third step is to extract the pairs that are to be retained

```
Flatten[MapThread[Take, {groups, m}], 1]
```

> ```
> {{-1028.4, -1011.7}, {-376.079, -386.7}, {43.3633, 93.3}, 
>  {325.51, 345.3}, {291.146, 345.3}, {1697.32, 1688.3}}
> ```

Comment: This does not give the correct result.

Comment: @ciao. You're right. I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: @ciao. I think it's fixed.

Comment: Beats me - I've still not re-installed 10 (waiting for fixes), but the order does not match OP, I assume that matters... perhaps not. But +1 for clever.

Comment: @ciao. You're right about order. I presume it does **not** matter. My result is nicely sorted. Personally, I would prefer that, but it is certainly the OP's call, and I hope he/she will let us know.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly same approach than @m_goldberg but using `GroupBy` and `MinimalBy` :

```
Values@GroupBy[tabul, Last, MinimalBy[#, Abs[Differences[#]] &,
 Count[data, Last@First@#]] &]
```

> `{{-376.079, -386.7}}, {{-1028.4, -1011.7}}, {{325.51, 345.3}, {291.146, 345.3}}, {{1697.32, 1688.3}}, {{43.3633, 93.3}}}`

Comment: +1 Nice use of some the new functions introduced in V10